# How to implement a class which is used on a mixin?

Tags: dart

The following code comes from the [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins)

```dart
class Musician {}
mixin MusicalPerformer on Musician {}
class SingerDancer extends Musician with MusicalPerformer {}
```

Docs says:

> In the preceding code, only classes that extend or implement the Musician class can use the mixin MusicalPerformer.

However, if I do the `implements` part, I get a compile error:

```
class SingerDancer implements Musician with MusicalPerformer {} // Compile error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix-in a mixin, the *superclass* of the mixin application must implement the `on` requirements of the mixin. The superclass is the class before the `with`.

The `class SingerDancer extends Musician with MusicalPerformer {}` works because the superclass, `Musician`, implements (trivially) the interface `Musician`, and therefore you can apply `MusicalPerformer` to it.

If you have a class:

```dart
class SingerDancer implements Musician { ... }
```

then you can apply `MusicalPerformer` to it:

```dart
class SingerDancerPerformer = SingerDancer with MusicalPerformer;
```

However, when you write:

```dart
class SingerDancer implements Musician with MusicalPerformer {}
```

the parts are in the wrong order. If it was allowed, it would perhaps mean

```dart
class SingerDancer with MusicalPerformer implements Musician {}
```

aka.

```dart
class SingerDancer extends Object with MusicalPerformer implements Musician {}
```

(If you omit the `extends X` before `with` it's implicitly `extends Object`, just as if you omit `extends X` on a class without a `with`).
Here the superclass of the mixin application does not implement `Musician`.
It's also not allowed at all because `implements` cannot come before `extends`/`with` in the class declaration.

The class just before the `with` must satisfy the requirements of the mixin (for multiple mixins, like `extends X with M1, M2`, the class before `M2` is the mixin application `X with M1`).

Comment: Thanks, however, the answer isn't easy for me to understand. (1) "Musician, implements (trivially) the interface Musician" -- In this statement do you want to say "Musician, *has* (trivially) the interface Musician". (2) Does `class SingerDancer with MusicalPerformer` mean I'm already implementing (`implements`) `Musician` class? +1 though!

Comment: Ad (1), yes, the `Musician` *class* implements/has a number of interfaces, either directly declared or inherited. One of those interfaces is the class's own interface. So the `Musician` *class* implements/has the `Musician` *interface* (which are technically two separate things). Ad (2) The `class SingerDancer with MusicalPerformer ...` is not a valid declaration because the superclass of the mixin application `with MusicalPerformer` is the implict `extends Object`, and `MusticalPerformer` needs a `Musician` as superclass. It's impossible to say what it means since it's not valid Dart.

Comment: If you have `class X extends Y with MuscialPerformer {}`, and it's valid (meaning that `Y` implements `Musician`), then `X` also implements the `Musician`, `MuscialPerformer`, `Y` and `Object` interfaces (along with any other interfaces `Y` happens to have).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `implements` you should do:

```
class SingerPerformer implements Musician, MusicalPerformer {}
```

Edited:
`MusicalPerfomer` depends on the superclass `Musician`. `SingerPerformer` is not a subclass of `Musician`, but will implement its interface. So `SingerPerformer` **cannot** use the mixin, but it can implement its interface also.

Second Edit:
You can also do this:

```
class NewMusician implements Musician {}
class NewPerformer extends NewMusician with MusicalPerformer {}
```

Comment: But then you're implementing mixin, I want to implement class not mixin.

Comment: But the doc comment says something else, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Can you please reread?